# WCF Service Error - Maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded

Tags: asp.net, wcf, silverlight, wcf-binding

All,

I have an WCF service (in asp.net 4.0 web app), running in asp.net compatibility mode.
When my silverlight  client posts a large chunk of data to the service Save(SomeLargeObject), I receive this message from the server (400-Bad Request). I traced the error on the server and got this from the service:

The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, 
use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.

To resolve the error I haved updated my server service config file (web.config):

```
<bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WebStoreServices_BasicHttpBinding" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MyBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
      </wsHttpBinding>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="NewBinding0" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

and my Silverlight client serivce config file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IWebStoreServices" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                    <security mode="None" />
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:1271/Services/WebStoreServices.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IWebStoreServices"
                contract="WebStore.IWebStoreServices" name="BasicHttpBinding_IWebStoreServices" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

I still get the above error on the server, "maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536)", it is like my binding on the server is ignored. Why is it ignoring my settings! I did use the WCF tool to create the bindings to avoid errors.

Comment: Can you show at least one example of your service configuration (i.e. one declaration of a service endpoint in your <system.serviceModel><services> element)

Comment: Issue resolved, thanks for your help. Yes, my system.service model had nothing else but the binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The settings seem fine - but does the server-side endpoint using the `basicHttpBinding` **actually reference** that binding configuration with the increased `MaxReceivedMessageSize` setting at all??

You should have a setup something like this in your server-side `web.config`:

```
<services>
   <service name="WebStore.WebStoreServices">
       <!-- this endpoint uses basicHttpBinding and uses the binding configuration -->
       <endpoint name="basicHttp"
           address="......"
           binding="basicHttpBinding"
           bindingConfiguration="WebStoreServices_BasicHttpBinding" 
           contract="WebStore.IWebStoreServices" />
   </service>
</services>
```

If your `basicHttpBinding` endpoint is **missing** the `bindingConfiguration="..."` setting - well, then you've defined the binding configuration alright, but you're not actually **using** it!

Comment: Thanks for the fix, it works now,- my problem was that I did not have anything else defined besides the binding in the web.config. It was my first WCF service, I thought it would somehow associate binding w/ my coded service w/out any extra config entries.